# Querying Core Data with Predicates - iPhone

Tags: iphone

So I'm trying to fetch objects from core data. I have list of say 80 objects, and I want to be able to search through them using a UISearchBar.  They are displayed in a table.

Using the apple documentation on predicates, I've put the following code in one
of the UISearchBar delegate methods.

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
  if (self.searchBar.text !=nil)
  {
    NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name LIKE %@", self.searchBar.text];
    [fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
  }
  else
  {
    NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"All"];
    [fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
  }

  NSError *error = nil;
  if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        // Handle error
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();  // Fail
    }       

  [self.tableView reloadData];

    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];   
    [_shadeView setAlpha:0.0f];
}
```

If I type in the search field an exact match to the name property of one of those objects, the search works, and it repopulates the table with a single cell with the name of the object.  If I don't search the name exact, I end up with no results.

Any Thoughts?

Comment: sorry about the lack for formatting on the code, i forgot to add the code sample tags

Comment: You can edit your post to format the code correctly...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems as though iPhone doesn't like the LIKE operator.  I replaced it with 'contains[cd]' and it works the way I want it to.

Answer (score 5):

use contains[cd] instead of like, and change:

`NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"All"];`

to:

`NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"1=1"];`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try it using MATCH and regular expressions? Just curious to see if LIKE is something that should be avoided on the iPhone or not...

Comment: Ya, match causes an exception to be thrown.  Its just odd because apple uses the LIKE operator a lot in their documentation, but it doesn't work the way it says it should.

Answer (score 1):

In typical Core Data application one should delete NSF fetchedResultsController:

```
[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName: [self.fetchedResultsController cacheName]];
```

Or else you'll get an exception (ideally) or you'll have strange behavior.