# Using predicate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nspredicate

I want to have a  textfield for search which displays as in google's suggest,i.e When I type 'a' the table view should be filled with all words starting with 'a' retrieved from db.My question is how to use predicate for querying from db.(as in 'a%' in mysql)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you even need `NSPredicate` when `like` statement in *sql* has the ability to do this for you?

Comment: yea there is...But I want to do the same using core data which is more flexible

Comment: Alrgiht.. I guess you can use `CONTAINS`, `BEGINSWITH` or `ENDSWITH` keyword of `NSPredicate` whichever suits your need..

Comment: Which database engine are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSPredicate has the keywords `CONTAINS`, `BEGINSWITH` and `ENDSWITH` which are similar to `like` statement in *sql*. You can do the *case insensitive* comparison using the key characters `c` and `d` within *square braces* to specify *case* and *diacritic* insensitivity respectively (for example `[c]`, `[d]` or `[cd]`).

You can read more on [Predicate Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW1). Moreover, this [Querying Core Data with Predicates - iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019070/querying-core-data-with-predicates-iphone) SO post has some discussion which I think will help you in this regard.

**Note:** Thanks to @Dave DeLong. His first comment below here, adds to this answer.

Comment: There's also `LIKE` and `MATCHES`.  The first is your conventional SQL-style "like" (Bob*, etc), and the latter is for a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for being so terse, but everything you need to know about using an `NSPredicate` to retrieve data from your iOS app's database can be found in the [Predicate Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001789) by Apple available on their web site. Read all of it and play with the examples. If you then have more specific questions about using them, feel free to come back and ask.